# How to separately define a nested class member function with the outer class templated?

Tags: c++

I am writing a template class with a inner struct(public class). Now I have problems while defining the member function of the inner struct.

In the header file,

```
template <typename T>
class TMatrix {
    ...
    struct Triplet {

        void nop() const;

    };
    ...
};
```

To define the function nop, in another cpp file I wrote

```
template <typename T>
void TMatrix<T>::Triplet::nop() {...}
// or
// void typename TMatrix<T>::Triplet::nop() {...}
```

But both of the two form don't compile. g++ says

```
error: expected unqualified-id before ‘)’ token
```

How can I correctly define this function separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is working fine except you have to add const in function definition

```
template <typename T>
void TMatrix<T>::Triplet::nop() const {}  // <--const is added in function declaration
```

You can check working example here

http://ideone.com/Yeio3w